# Row color problem with @{\hspace}

Tags: tables, rowcolor

I wanted to create a table that has the textwidth without using tabularx, so I used tabcolsep and hskip to keep the text left-aligned. But now I have an issue with the rowcolor as seen in the picture and I can't fix it. [image]

```
\begin{table}[H]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{63} % Default value: 6pt
\begin{tabular}{|@{\hskip5pt}l|@{\hskip5pt}l|@{\hskip5pt}l|}
\hline 
\rowcolor{Gray} \textbf{Ljudklass} & \textbf{Ekvivalentnivå} & \textbf{Maximalnivå} \\ 
\hline
C                  & 30                      & 45                   \\ \hline
B                  & 26                      & 41                   \\ \hline
A                  & 22                      & 37                   \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: please provide a complete test file not just a fragment. Don't you get a missing unit error  from`\setlength{\tabcolsep}{63} % Default value: 6pt` ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... Is this helps you `\begin{table}[H]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{28pt}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline 
\rowcolor{gray}
....`